# Gremlin - count number of edges where two properties differ

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

Given a vertex `g.V(1)`, with *x* outbound edges.

Say `g.V(1)` has the properties `prop1` and `prop2` on each of its outbound edges.

**How can I find the number of times where those two properties differ?**

For example (say there's three outbound edges), if `g.V(1).outE().values('prop1')` returns:

```
==> A
==> B
==> C
```

And if `g.V(1).outE().values('prop2')` returns:

```
==> A
==> D
==> E
```

**We should get an answer of 2**: (B!=D, C!=E, but A==A)

Something similar to:

```
g.V(1).where(neq(outE().values('prop1'), outE().values('prop2'))).count()
```

(but which actually works!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When asking questions about Gremlin it is always best to include some sample data like this:

```
g.addV().property('pid','a').as('a').
  addV().property('pid','b').as('b').
  addE('link').from('a').to('b').property('prop1','A').property('prop2','A').
  addE('link').from('a').to('b').property('prop1','B').property('prop2','D').
  addE('link').from('a').to('b').property('prop1','C').property('prop2','E').iterate()
```

You can do what you're looking for with `where()` step:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('pid','a').
......1>   outE().as('compare').
......2>   where('compare', neq('compare')).
......3>     by('prop1').by('prop2').
......4>   valueMap()
==>[prop2:D,prop1:B]
==>[prop2:E,prop1:C]
```